# Having trouble calling a method to edit a string from another class in java

Tags: java, methods

I've got a simple java program that is supposed to take the specified characters in a string and print them back out to the user by doing everything within a secondary method in a secondary class while taking input from the user in the first class.

The problem that I'm having is that when I try to invoke the secondary method in my main method, I get an error that says "The method copy(String) is unidentified for my main method.

My code for the main method is:

```
    System.out.println("Copying - Enter a string");
            String currentString = input.next();
            System.out.println("The current string is: " + currentString);
            System.out.println("Enter the starting position");
            int startPosition = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter one past the ending position");
            int onePastLastPosition = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("The new string is: " + copy(currentString));
```

And for the copy method is:

```
public static String copy(String currentString, int startPosition, int onePastLastPosition) { 
        currentString = currentString.substring(startPosition, onePastLastPosition); 
        return currentString;
    }
```

So for example, what the code is supposed to do, is if I input a string "abcd", it returns back to me "bc", but the system gets hung up on the last line in the first method.
Any help with understanding where I went wrong, and how to fix it in the future would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide the method the necessary parameters for it to execute properly.

Method `copy` is accepting three parameters: `currentString`, `startPosition`, `onePastLastPosition` as per the parameters specified:

```
public static String copy(String currentString, int startPosition, int onePastLastPosition) {
```

So you should be calling the method like so:

```
System.out.println("The new string is: " + copy(currentString, startPosition, onePastLastPosition));
```

**Test Run**

```
Copying - Enter a string
spectric
The current string is: spectric
Enter the starting position
1
Enter one past the ending position
2
The new string is: p
```

Answer (score 2):

Your copy method is in different class.You have to create the second class instance in first class to call the second class function.

First class

```
System.out.println("Copying - Enter a string");
        ....   
System.out.println("The new string is: " + 
SecondClass.copy(currentString));
```

***P/S : Make sure the number of the parameters are correct.***

Comment: It's a static method.

Comment: Why the downvote? If `ClassA` needs to call a method that exists inside `ClassB`, then the method needs to be declared as `static` or you need to instantiate `ClassB` and call the method through a reference to that instance. In either case, you can't just call `copy()` from `ClassA`. It needs to be either `ClassB.copy()` or `classBInstance.copy()`.

Comment: Also, @Spectric, while it's unnecessary, it's not impossible to call a `static` method through an instance of the owning class. But I probably would've gone with the `SecondClass.copy()` variant to emphasize the `static` modifier as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your `copy` method is `static`, so you should call the method with class prefix, and pass additional arguments (`startPosition`, `onePastLastPosition`) you declared.

```java
System.out.println("The new string is: " + YourClassName::copy(currentString, startPosition, onePastLastPosition))
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

- your parameters to copy are different than the method signature shows.
- you should be calling Copy as a static by prefixing the name of the containing class.

Answer (score 1):

The copy method requires 3 parameters, but you have only provided 1. Add the other two:

```
copy(currentString, startPosition, onePastLastPosition)
```

---

Add an import statement for the copy method:

```
import static SecondClass.copy;
```

Or qualify the method:

```
SecondClass.copy(currentString, startPosition, onePastLastPosition)
```